# Consul was uninstalled from k3s cluster yet it is still trying to inject to deployment

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, consul

I was testing out consul on my k3s cluster. After testing it out, I have removed the consul namespace and did a helm uninstall. Consul should be completely removed from the k3s cluster. However, I am getting the following error below for any application deployments. It seems like somewhere in the k3s cluster, there are some default consul settings to inject consul into the pods.

```
'Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "consul-connect-injector.consul.hashicorp.com":
      Post "https://consul-connect-injector-svc.consul-system.svc:443/mutate?timeout=10s":
      service "consul-connect-injector-svc" not found'
```

When inspecting the replicaset manifest. no annotations were specified anywhere to do a consul inject. I've also tried to add in **consul.hashicorp.com/connect-inject: "false"** but I'm still getting similar results.

```
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: testapp
      pod-template-hash: 7c8d846556
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name:  testapp
        pod-template-hash: 7c8d846556
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: 
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: testapp 
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
        resources: {}
```

Answer (score 1):

I realized that after uninstalling the consul, the mutatingwebhooks of the consul are not removed. Went ahead to remove the 2 consul webhooks from `kubectl get MutatingWebhookConfiguration <consul-webhook-name>`. But I am not sure why the webhooks aren't removed when the uninstall command was ran.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to identify the issue to unblock your pod deployments. I saw you created https://github.com/hashicorp/consul/issues/11954 to report the issue of the webhook not being removed. Our team will investigate this issue and follow up there with any questions.